# Cannot authorize variable group in Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am constructing a multi-stage Azure Pipeline in Azure DevOps to build and release my product.

I want to use variable groups in this pipeline, so that I can substitute different configuration values for different deployment environments.

I am unable to authorize my variable groups to be used by the pipeline.
When I manually run a build, I see a message on the summary page telling me the variable group is not authorized:
[image: Error message]

The [Azure DevOps documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops) says this is to be expected:

> When you make changes to the YAML file and add additional resources (assuming that these not authorized for use in all pipelines as explained above), then the build fails with a resource authorization error that is similar to the following: Could not find a {RESOURCE} with name {NAME}. **The {RESOURCE} does not exist or has not been authorized for use.**
>
> In this case, **on the Summary page, you will see an option to authorize the resources on the failed build**. If you are a member of the User role for the resource, you can select this option. Once the resources are authorized, you can start a new build.

I am a member of the User role for the variable group, and I am seeing the message, but I am presented with no option to authorize. Is there something else I need to do? Or is there another way I can authorize a specific pipeline to use a variable group?

Comment: Do you create variable group manually or link Azure key vault?

Comment: I created the variable group manually.

Comment: Sorry if it's too obvious question, but do you have ["Allow access to all pipelines"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#use-a-variable-group) set to true for your variable group?

Comment: No, fair question. I've consciously set that to "False" because there are sensitive variables in these groups and I want to minimise entities with access to them. If I set it to "True" then the pipeline can access the variables.

Comment: Hi,Peter Is the situation I am referring to is the cause of your issue? If you have any question ,please kindly let me know :)

Comment: Thanks Hugh, I will give your proposed solution a try shortly and let you know if it solves my problem.

Comment: none of these solutions work for my issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Variable groups can only be accessed if they are imported at the "job" level.

### Solution:

I have tested and tried to reproduce your issue. In order to solve it, you need to add the variable group under "job".

### Explanation / Analysis:

This is how to reproduce and solve the issue:

First, I have tested with the below `yaml` script, by adding the variable group to the **stage** (literally at the same level as **jobs**):

```
stages:
- stage: build
  variables:
    - group: 789
  jobs:
  - job: run_build
    pool:
      vmImage: 'Ubuntu 16.04'
    steps:
    - script: echo Build
```

With this configuration, I was not able to use the variable group. I got the same issue as you:

[image]

I then moved the variable group into the **job** section of the `yaml` file:

```
stages:
- stage: build
  jobs:
  - job: run_build
    pool:
      vmImage: 'Ubuntu 16.04'
    steps:
    - script: echo Build
    variables:
    - group: 789
```

With the modified configuration, I was able to see and use the **Authorize resources** option in the error message:

[image]

Comment: good to know. I actually didn't know this. however mine is as you described on the job and still doesn't work.

Answer (score 16):

The provided solution proposed by @hey didn't work for me because i had to use deployment jobs. I've found a hacky way to resolve this error:

1. Go to your pipeline
2. Edit
3. Click on the tree dots > Triggers
4. Navigate to the variables tab
5. Variable groups
6. Add variable groups

Comment: I like this better since it's making an actual config change and not just forcing an error to get the button you want

Comment: I arrived at 'Variables groups' and need to "Link variable group" because I was trying to use an existing variable group. Super annoying- DevOps was making this look like an authorization issue with my secure file (that the variable in my variable group was pointing to). Instead of presenting us with an "Authorize resource" button- it should've been showing a "Link variable group" button...

Comment: I did as your guide. It's working fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I followed this and removed restrictions from all of the variable groups I'm using and it still fails with that error message.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue as well, but it was because when I created a variable group under Pipelines > Library, the name in Azure Portal did not match the name in my yml file.

Comment: I faced almost the same issue, the only difference is that I had a parameterized variable group name in my vars.yml file. Unfortuntately it does not work this way, so once the parameter in the yml file was replaced with actual variable group name - everything worked.